Как слово "нелицеприятный" превратилось в слово "неприятный"?
ДИАЛОГ
— Как? Да очень просто, пользователи считывают  значение слова с его  морфемного состава: неприятный для конкретного лица.
— Неправильно считывают! Надо так:  без принятия во внимание значимости этого конкретного лица для говорящего  (начальник, родственник, друг хороший). Правильное значение: беспристрастный, справедливый: НЕЛИЦЕПРИЯТНЫЙ. Книжн. Беспристрастный, справедливый. Н-ая критика. Н. отзыв. Н-ое мнение.
— Вот именно что книжное слово, в словаре надо смотреть!  А оно уже становится разговорным. Тогда надо внести в словарь это значение — и нет проблем.
АЛЕКСАНДРА МАРИНИНА. СТЕЧЕНИЕ ОБСТОЯТЕЛЬСТВ. 
https://polka.academy/materials/825
А главная постсоветская детективная писательница 
проиллюстрирует для нас относительно недавнюю ошибку 
— она начинает появляться в литературных текстах 
ровно в начале 1990-х, что, кажется, говорит об 
ударе, постигшем в это время институт редактуры. Это 
слово «нелицеприятный», которое путают с 
«неприятный» (на самом деле оно значит 
«непредвзятый», «беспристрастный»). В «Стечении 
обстоятельств» Анастасия Каменская, «сидя в низком 
кресле перед нависающим над ней начальником… 
готовилась услышать что-нибудь нелицеприятное». В 
«Чужой маске» одна героиня шантажирует другую: «Я 
могу рассказать о вас множество нелицеприятных 
вещей», а в «Мужских играх» можно прочитать: 
«Дизайнер и архитектор… давали ему самые 
нелицеприятные оценки, называя «козлом, который сам 
не знает, чего хочет», и «придурком, который думает, 
что за «зелёные» бабки можно изменить законы 
физики».

Вопрос:  Надо вносить в словарь второе значение слова «нелицеприятный» в словарь  (нелицеприятный  =  неприятный)? Или еще подождать, поговорить?.. Какие перспективы у этого слова?
P. S. Интересное мнение:  Нелицеприятный — беспристрастный, но уже с оттенком некоторого скандальчика.

Не основанный на лицеприятии, беспристрастный. Нелицеприятное суждение. Ушаков. - тут скорее беспристрастный поменяло своё значение. Не+лице+приятный - не пытающийся угодить другим, неудобный для других, непринятый в обществе, выходящий за рамки поведенческих представлений и шаблонов.

Ну это сложное слово, тут надо понимать, что такое лица-лицо, что такое приятный. Приятный сегодня получило некий положительный смысл, хотя приятель - это не друг, а полудруг, дружок. Приятель можно употреблять в негативном ключе. И слово френд переводится не как "друг", а именно как приятель.

за «зелёные» бабки можно изменить законы
физики» - не совсем так, это изменение не одного конкретного слова, а целой группы слов. И «"зелёные" бабки»?) И слова - это не законы физики, не совсем так или вообще не так.

"Гоголь был в этих случаях строгий, нелицеприятный судья и оценщик."Анненков. Тут не совсем "беспристрастный", скорее "несговорчивый".

Все верно, но  здесь два варианта:  Начальник говорит что-то неприятное для меня, на то он и начальник.  //  Я говорю неприятную для начальника, но справедливую  критику.

Будем вносить в словарь второе значение?

Начальник всегда прав) начальник есть главный судья) а всякие работники начальников не судят, но это вообще комплексное изменение нравов и пониманий.

Мне кажется, наиболее точное - "несговорчивый", пока, по крайней мере. Беспристрастный тоже даёт какую-то положительную оценку, а у этого слова нет положительной или отрицательной оценки, это неверно. Это не положительное качество, а какое-то свойство, когда человек настаивает на своём, при этом, не значит, что он прав. Как слово "строгий" - это положительное качество или отрицательное? Смотря для кого ведь? Оценщик он же критик - положительное или отрицательное качество? Сама логика деления слов на "положительные" и "отрицательные" в корне неверна и русскому языку скорее несвойственна.

А вот английскому - таки да, там слова именно что делятся на положительные и отрицательные. А в русском языке слово может иметь положительный или отрицательны оттенок в зависимости от контекста. В русском большинство слов - нейтральны.

Здесь все-таки чувствуется намеренный негативный подтекст (неприятный!).  Пусть даже справедливый,  но  бесцеремонный, недипломатичный.  Человек может воспринять критику, но отношения будут испорчены.  Вот начинающий писатель просит беспристрастно оценить его  творчество. Не поддавайтесь на провокацию!

Здесь все-таки чувствуется намеренный негативный подтекст (неприятный!). - это не к русскому языку, а к конкретному человеку, который не сдерживает своих негативных или позитивных оценок при изложении мыслей - не "фильтрует базар"). Это общая культурная деградация, а не язык. Я про это деструктивное влияние и говорю, что из-за наплыва грамматики английского языка, многое было понятно неверно, так как в английском другая система передачи мыслей да и вообще другое мышление. И этот негатив, как и эмоциональный позитив, который стал поддерживаться, и ведёт к этому разложению на два полюса.

Здесь все-таки чувствуется намеренный негативный подтекст (неприятный!).  - это не слово искажено, а искажение восприятия языка вообще, потому что происходит восприятие русских слов, через "грамматику" или правила формирования фраз английского языка. Происходит смесь языковых систем и это отражается на восприятии слов и фраз, привнося семантику, ту которой там должно по-идее быть.

Но русский язык фразеологический, каждое слово - это фраза. Это, вероятно, наследие от немецкого (или совместное наследие, поэтому слово легко раскладывается на части - не лице приятный - не приятный лицу или лицам. То есть получается слово-фраза. И тут нужно определять уже не "нелицеприятный", а "приятный" и "лицо" каждый корень отдельно и во взаимодействии. Как это быть не при+ятным лицу? Вот это логика русского языка, а вовсе не "положительная" или "отрицательная" эмоция.

То есть логика "положительное это слово или отрицательное" - не верная логика, это не логика русского языка.

А английскому эта логика досталась от вульгарной латыни, когда варвары не знали, что есть то или иное сложное или простое слово, и ориентировались на "сена-солома" - правое оно или левое, хорошее или плохое и тп. Да и бог римлян был двуликий Янус, это бинарность заложена в принципе в их языке. А в русском слова неразделённые на право и лево. Муж и жена вместе семья и тп, если есть дихотомия, то она объединяется во что-то целое, русский язык троичный, а не бинарный.

Это не значит, что одна логика лучше другой, но смешивать эти логики нужно очень осторожно.

Не поддавайтесь на провокацию! - да я согласен, но проблема носит более общий характер, а не конкретно одно неверно воспринятое слово или даже правило.

Лингвисты уже давно говорят,что это слово вошло в узус. Трудно сказать, почему в Большой толковый словарь его до сих пор не включили. Наверное, стоит уточнить на Грамоте. ру

Не+лиц+е+при+ятный.
Отрицание от приятный (съедобный, удобный, угождающий, любезный, лестный) лицу-лицам. Где "лица" - это мирское, внешнее проявление человека, суетное, а не внутреннее духовное-душевное.
Поэтому НЕЛИЦЕПРИЯТНЫЙ - холодный, рассудительный, неподкупный, вызывающий раздражение, насмешливый, саркастичный, честный. Независимый, неподкупный, несговорчивый, непримиримый с лицемерием,  неуступчивый ("душный" по-современному, душнила или провокатор), неудобный... Нелицеприятный суд, нелицеприятный государь, нелицеприятный начальник.
Можно использовать в споре для оскорбления, хотя как такового негативного смысла, кроме как по отношению к "лицу" с которым нелицеприятный человек дело имеет, в нём нет.

Приятели сходились также друг у друга на чайные вечера, где всякий очередной хозяин старался превзойти другого разнообразием, выбором и изяществом кренделей, прибавляя всегда, что они куплены на вес золота. Гоголь был в этих случаях строгий, нелицеприятный судья и оценщик. На этих сходках царствовала веселость, бойкая насмешка над низостью и лицемерием, которой журнальные, литературные и всякие другие анекдоты служили пищей, по особенно любил Гоголь составлять куплеты и песни на общих знакомых.
П. В. Анненков. Литературные воспоминания (1882)


При нем был, следственно, суд немздоимный, нелицеприятный, ни весьма спешный, ни весьма медленный. Фонвизин.

Кому нравится, когда с ним поступают строго и оценивают его поведение, судят? Да обычно никому из современных индивидуалистов. То есть людей, не готовых признавать общие представления морали и следовать нравственным ориентирам, а опирающихся только на собственную выгоду и эгоизм, ищущих что-то приятное и удовольствие для себя.

ИНДИВИДУАЛИЗМ
(франц. individualisme), тип мировоззрения, сутью которого является в конечном счёте абсолютизация позиции отд. индивида в его
противопоставленности обществу, причём не какому-то определ.
социальному строю, а обществу вообще. И. проявляется как в реальной жизненной позиции — в поступках, так и в различных концепциях — этич., филос., идеологич., политич. и т. п. Концепции И. изображают человека как изначально несоциальное и даже антисоциальное существо (см. также Эгоизм, Анархизм). Философский энциклопедический словарь. — М.: Советская энциклопедия. Гл. редакция: Л. Ф. Ильичёв, П. Н. Федосеев, С. М. Ковалёв, В. Г. Панов. 1983.

Где анархия - это общество построенное без(нелицеприятных) законов, общество без государства. Где люди выстраивают только "приятные" отношения и делают то, что выгодно и удобно.

Такие рассказы заставляли смеяться; но ректор был высокий труженик,
подвижник долга, монах примерной жизни, нелицеприятный начальник. Н. П. Гиляров-Платонов. Из пережитого. Том 2 (1886)


Справедливый, нелицеприятный, настоящий русский царь изволил написать:
«Теперь мне дело ясно, Стогов прав». Э. И. Стогов. Записки (1870-1880)

Если вы кого-то считаете нелицеприятным, значит, этот человек ваш начальник.

Спасибо за ответ и интересное обсуждение темы!

Лицо и личность - это кстати, противоположные слова. Лицо - это поведение при взаимодействии, маска в ролевой игре, а личность, это внутреннее состояние, воплощение. Личность может быть нелицеприятной. А лицо не может быть нелицеприятным. πρόσωπον «лицо, личность» + ληπτός «воспринимаемый» - это вроде слова "неприличный".
(Hom. преимущ., Trag. часто pl.) лицо, облик (εἰς π. βλέπειν Eur.; βλέπειν τινὰ π. πρὸς π. NT.)
2) ( у животных) лицевая часть головы, т.е. морда

Вы думаете, неправильное объяснение  этимологии?  А как правильно?

Ну слово личность - тут лишнее, лицо, морда, облик - да, но не личность. Личность - это как раз то, что может быть нелицеприятным). Личность есть у Бога - Христос, личность Бога. А "Лица" у Христа нет что ли, поведенческого, животного. То есть вот это слово "лицо" постепенно перешло в разряд отрицаний - лицо, это не истинная форма. И ещё есть лицо как ипостась. Вот у Троицы, иконы, это Лица - ипостаси, а не лица - просопон.

πρόσωπον
4383 πρόσωπον
{сущ., 78}
лицо, вид, облик, личность; перен. поверхность.

ὑπόστασις
5287 ὑπόστασις
{сущ., 5}

сущность, естество;
реальность, действительность;
основание, фундамент;
уверенность, тв¸рдость, отважность;
личность, ипостась.


То есть один ряд - лицо, вид, облик, поверхность, личность, а другой- сущность, естество, основание, личность, ипостась. Два разных значения у слова личность. А у лица только одно.

Этимология слова:
Нелицеприятный – несомненно церковнославянское по происхождению слово. Фиксируется в памятниках XVII века, причём с морфологическим вариантом нелицеприемный [Словарь русского языка XI-XVII вв., том 11, стр. 163]. Оба варианта – кальки с греческого ἀπροσωπολήπτος (апросополептос) «беспристрастный» < ἀ - «не» + πρόσωπον «лицо, личность» + ληπτός «воспринимаемый». То есть, «неличновоспринимаемый» = беспристрастный.

С таким значением слово использовалось в течение долгого времени, это значение указано и в современном толковом словаре.

Но со временем могут появляться и другие значения. Часто это бывает связано с переносным (образным) значением. Книжное слово было использовано без учета основного значения (беспристрастный) и с подчеркиванием того, что критика всегда неприятна, даже если она справедлива.


